# Are the means of reopening questions fair?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I've asked a question...

[How to use ReadPrinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55798748)

There was some questioning about information that was tangential to the problem: e.g. "How does the printer receive the commands". I have no doubts about the form of communication; the command is correct!

I chose not to evidence such information in the matter so as not to be confused. The problem is occurring in the use of a library, Winspool / ReadPrinter. So my question was closed as "it is not clear what you are asking for".

I made the correction, and I informed all the information that was requested, even those that I do not think are necessary for the analysis... it's all there...

I believe I have followed every step I read to reopen, made the changes clear and complete, but it has not been reopened...

What more do I need now to reopen the issue?

Is it just dependence, uncertainty, to reopen a question?

PS: Practical measures/a privilege that I do not have... is not a solution, to me.

This question can not be considered duplicate since it does not deal with the presentation of the forms to reopen an question. What I put into discussion is whether these forms are valid, fair and workable.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This question can not be considered duplicate since it does not deal with the presentation of the forms to reopen an question , what I put into discussion is whether these forms are valid, fair and workable.

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not "deal with the presentation of the forms to reopen a question". The duplicate asks how to get a question reopened. The answers are the same; edit the question to ensure it reflects the close reason and comments. These are the basic steps for any closed questions, and have been reiterated here on Meta many times over.

Comment: What counts as, "fair"?  You need to define that.  Chances are good curators are going to have a very different opinion of what constitutes, "fair".

Comment: @Joelend Making a question Chameleon question is not welcome on either main or meta. If you feel that not every part of your original question covered by existing answers - ask new question. Rolling back your edit to restore validity of answers may be good idea. This is especially true for cases where answers already present (like this one) - you even keep answer accepted even if has absolutely nothing to do with new question.

Comment: I did not understand, be clearer, please.What should I do?

Comment: What should you do for what?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I did not understand what @Alexei Levenkov meant.

Comment: How can you? I justified why it is not duplicated, it is clear that my question is totally different. The question to which it relates relates to knowing the ways of reopening.

Comment: @Joelend (you've obviously searched for "chameleon question" and got [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) already)  You've edited this question from "how get question reopened" into totally different (and somewhat unclear) "is reopen process fair". By doing so you've completely invalidated answers (including accepted one). The right way of asking new question is to ask new question.

Comment: very difficult ... as a new member I hear the help of some users, often not clear ... and when I go to see this happens ... duplicate ... chameleon ... I leave here another appeal, it seems that the the oldest in the forum are more concerned with recriminating, denouncing, blocking than actually trying to teach trying to teach ...

Comment: What actions are being taken that are recriminating?  Or denouncing?  You're throwing around accusations, but don't seem to understand what the site's purpose really is.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

First of all, check *why* your question was closed:

- The close reason: unclear what you're asking.

  > Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
  >   If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

  So, it says that you have to edit your question. I see you have done it, however, it needs to be properly formatted. Do note that questions that are edited within 5 days of closure are pushed into the reopen queue
- The comments.

  People usually explain why they voted to close. Follow their advice and edit your question accordingly. Although in your question people didn't exactly and clearly explain why they downvoted, I believe it was a little bit unclear. There wasn't enough context to understand what you were asking.

Now, you correctly edited your post, adding lots of context. The problem was that your code was unformatted and the queue didn't take the time to edit it. It is better to format your posts properly. Remember that **the better your post looks, the easier it is for other people to read it**. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

I have edited it to format it. You may want to spend some time with it: improve the tagging, organise the stuff there, etc. For now, I threw it a reopen vote, there are some improvements to be made, though that should be done from your side.

Answer (score 7):

Your question was closed because it was not clear what you where asking and needs to be edited into better shape. Once you edit into a better question it gets put into the reopen queue where people can review it to see if it should be opened again. If 5 people agree that the question has been improved enough to warrant reopening and cast votes to do so it will be reopened.

It should be noted however that it may not be possible to edit the question into good enough shape to be reopened and even if you do the needed edits it might not be reopened.

As a side note you should not just make a new post to reask this question as that is not the proper way to go about getting a question answered after it was closed the first time around.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason for closing. Even considering it unfair I do not question the opinion of users.
My complaint is: after closing I did everything that is proposed ... in my opinion, it is complete.
Could moderates who opted for closure reassess and see if what they said was taken care of?

Comment: @Joelend the title of the question is still very much not great as it is as generic as you can make it; the answer to it is "read the manual". Your problem is not that you don't know how to use it, your problem is that when you do use it as documented, no data is received.